# Alternative to Beanstalk

Tags: git-svn

Since Beanstalk began to support GIT their SVN deployments have slowed down drastically. 
Google is throwing up no results and having never setup anything similar to Beanstalk does anybody have any advice.

At the moment Beanstalk handles the following:
 - SVN Hosting
 - Deployments (configurable for per commit or manual with varying servers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Codesion](http://codesion.com/) has free SVN storage, but no deployment in their free account. Also, it only allows one project and one user.

I am not aware of other alternatives.

Comment: @autonomatt I believe the OP thought Codesion was an appropriate answer. I edited this so it looks more like an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used them but rackspace has cloud offering and they have hosted SVN "App" as well. Surprisingly it's called beanstalk:)
http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/tools/applications/beanstalk-hassle-free-subversion-hosting/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would personally recommend switching to Mercurial (using BitBucket) or Git (using Beanstalk or GitHub). I think you'd find distributed version control is the way things will be in the future.

If you are stuck with SVN, you can always simply set up your own system on a shared or dedicated host (there are plenty of open source options for deployment from SVN). If you're looking for someone else to blame for backups and such, potential alternatives are [CodeBase](http://www.codebasehq.com/) or [codesion](http://codesion.com/products/free-plan.html).

Comment: Agree with you, I have been using BitBucket for more then a year and I am extremely happy with it. Considering it has issue tracker as well it really becomes developer's collaborating platform.

Comment: Yes, and as a sole developer, it is free. Being able to use the same account for my free (personal) work, and my professional work is invaluable. Not to mention mercurial is by far the most powerful version control I've ever used. In SVN I avoided merging as much as possible, but now I'm a merging fool. :) There's also nothing like being able to close an issue straight from my commit!

Comment: That's ok but I'm an SVN user still unimpressed with Beanstalk. Changing to Git or Mercurial is not an option for me. CodeBase looks good but at the same price as Basecamp and Beanstalk combined I'd be hesitant to switch.